# Tire Sidewall cracking. Should I replace?

Tags: tires

I just noticed a crack on the left front tyre of my car. Tyres are 2.5 years old. 
[image]
Should I replace it immediately?
If replacing is the best option, should I replace both front tyres or just the cracked one?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should be replaced immediately.  Check the other side closely though.  It looks like plenty of tread depth is left, so this is a bit unusual.  If you purchased these new there may still be some warranty left so check with the dealer who sold them to you.

Comment: Should I replace both front tyres or just the cracked one?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to have both tires on the same axle the same make and model but it's not a hard-and-fast requirement in my opinion.  If the other one is still in good shape and you can get a similar or identical replacement, then keep the other one.  If the other one is mostly worn or has similar cracking or you can't get a new one like it, then replace both if you can.

Comment: Looks like tread rubber separating from the carcass, a manufacturing defect.

Comment: @pahan It's also a very good general idea to have the better tires on back. That way, should you lock your brakes, the back wheels will have more traction and not be as inclined to slide in front of your front wheels.